# Javascript mathematics with decimal calculation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net

I have a weird problem with javascript mathematics here is my code :

```
<script>
function four() {
    var price = document.getElementById("price").value;
    var sood = (price * 2.5) / 100;
    var pricetopay = price + sood ;
    var pishpardakht = pricetopay / 3;
    document.getElementById("PISH").value = pishpardakht;
    var mabaghi = pricetopay - pishpardakht;
    var ghest = mabaghi / 4;
    document.getElementById("GHEST").value = ghest;
}
</script>
```

and when the price is 100 ( price = 100 ) 
pish : 334.1666666666667
ghest : 167.08333333333331

how can i fix that ?

Comment: Fix what? You haven't explained specific problem or expected results. Please take a few minutes to read [ask] and [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution you had to parse the value that you get from your element.

```js
function four() {
    var priceUnparsed = document.getElementById("price").value;
   var price= parseFloat(priceUnparsed );
    var sood = (price * 2.5) / 100;
    var pricetopay = price + sood ;
    var pishpardakht = pricetopay / 3;
    alert(pishpardakht);
    document.getElementById("PISH").value = pishpardakht;
    var mabaghi = pricetopay - pishpardakht;
    var ghest = mabaghi / 4;
    document.getElementById("GHEST").value = ghest;
}
```

```html
<input id="price" value="100">
<button onclick="four()">Go</button>
```